# Isolate g(t) starting from $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g^{2}(t)e^{-i2\pi f t}dt$

Tags: frequency-spectrum

Is it possible to isolate $g(t)$ starting from
$G^2(f)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g^{2}(t)e^{-i2\pi f t}dt$ ? Can you show me how?

Comment: Please check your formula. Are you sure about the exponent?

Comment: @MattL. Thanks. I corrected

Comment: For the record, there also  exists a literature on recovering $g$ from the squared magnitude of the Fourier transform:  $|\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(t)e^{-i2\pi f t}\mathrm{d}t|^{2}$.

Comment: If $G(f)$ denotes the Fourier transform of $g(t)$, then the Fourier transform of $g^2(t)$ is **not** $G^2(f)$  (nor is it $|G(f)|^2$, for that matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral is the Fourier transform of $g^2(t)$, so an inverse Fourier transform can recover $g^2(t)$. But without any further information you can't recover $g(t)$ from $g^2(t)$. So the problem is not the integral transform but simply the squaring operation.

Comment: Is it not possible to do the square root?

Comment: Why it is not possible to recover $g(t)$ from $g^{2}(t)$?

Comment: @LucaMirtanini: Assuming that $g(t)$ is real-valued, $g^2(t)$ is always positive, right?

Comment: @MardyOwens: The square root of $g^2(t)$ is generally not equal to $g(t)$. Instead you get $\sqrt{g^2(t)}=|g(t)|$, so unless you know that $g(t)\ge 0$ (or $g(t)\le 0$) for all $t$ there's no way to recover $g(t)$ from $g^2(t)$.

Comment: Ok. To do the square root is like to do the absolute value. So the information about negative value are lost.